# jquery .load() function multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i load a test.html multiple time using **jQuery**.

```
function loadScreen()
{
  $('#result').load('test.html');
}
```

**main.html**

```
<div id='result'></div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="loadScreen()">
```

**test.html**

```
<body>
<p>
testing
</p>
</body>
```

**Current situation**

when i click the button click me. it will load once
show on main.html
testing

**what i want to do**

How can i do it when i click the button twice
it will show

```
testing
testing
```

and with different div id

1st time button click show testing  `<div id="result1">testing</div>`
2nd time button click show testing  `<div id="result2">testing</div>`

it will append incremental 1 at id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`load()` will replace the content of the target element which is why it's not working as you want.

Try this instead:

```
function loadScreen() {
    var divId = $("#result > div").length + 1;
    $('#result').append("<div></div>").attr("id", "result" + divId).load('test.html');
}
```

Comment: hmm i can't still unable to load test.html multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Then it's about time you should use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), then create a div via the [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), add in the contents using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) and [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) the results div.

```
var result = $('#result'),            //cache result box
    i = 0;

function loadScreen(){
    $.get('test.html',function(data){ //initiate get
        $('<div>',{                   //create div for return data
            id : 'result'+(++i)       //add attributes
        })
        .html(data)                   //add data
        .appendTo(result);            //append to result
    });
}
```

Comment: hmm when i click the button 2nd time.nothing happen